# Cakephp 3 how do i save individual date in database

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have leave request form.If users takes 2/3 days leaves, then the leave date should be stored into the database separately.I have applied for 2 days, suppose i have selected the date 20-10-2019 and 21-10-2019 for leave request. But it stored into database only one entry. date_form and date_to are my column names.
I want to separate the dates. Example : date_from: 20-10-2019 date_to : 20-10-2019 and  date_from: 21-10-2019 date_to : 21-10-2019. 
But now it stored date_from : 20-10-2019 date_to : 21-10-2019. Can anyone help me on this?

I have tried some code:

```
            else if($leaveRequest->no_of_days > 1 && $leaveRequest->no_of_days < 7)
            {
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $leaveRequest->no_of_days; $i++)
            {
                $day = $i. ' day';
                $var = $this->EmpLeaves->newEntity();

                if($i == 0)
                {
                $var->date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_from'])));
                $var->date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_from'])));
                }

                else
                {
                $var->date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day,strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_from']))));
                $var->date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day,strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_from']))));
                }

                $var->employee_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $var->employee_name = $this->request->getData(['employee_name']);
                $var->reporting_managerId = $this->request->getData(['reporting_managerId']);
                $var->leave_type = $this->request->getData(['leave_type']);
                // $var->no_of_days = $this->request->getData(['no_of_days']);
                 $var->no_of_days = 1;
                $var->half_day = $this->request->getData(['half_day']);
                $var->leave_reason = $this->request->getData(['leave_reason']);
                $var->reliever = $this->request->getData(['reliever']);
                $valueSaved = $this->EmpLeaves->save($var);
            }

            if($valueSaved)
            {
                //newcode for sending email
                 $applierEmail = $this->Auth->user('office_email');
                $applierName  = $this->Auth->user('first_name') . ' ' . $this->Auth->user('last_name');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Please check the message'));
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, you always want `date_from` and `date_to` to be equal? What would be the point of having both columns, then?

Answer (score 0):

```
         else if($leaveRequest->no_of_days > 1 && $leaveRequest->no_of_days < 7)
        {
        for($i = 0 ; $i < $leaveRequest->no_of_days; $i++)
        {
            $day = $i. ' day';
            $var = $this->EmpLeaves->newEntity();

           

            else
            
            $var->date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day,strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_from']))));
            $var->date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day,strtotime($this->request->getData(['date_to']))));
            

            $var->employee_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $var->employee_name = $this->request->getData(['employee_name']);
            $var->reporting_managerId = $this->request->getData(['reporting_managerId']);
            $var->leave_type = $this->request->getData(['leave_type']);
            $var->no_of_days = $this->request->getData(['no_of_days']);
            $var->half_day = $this->request->getData(['half_day']);
            $var->leave_reason = $this->request->getData(['leave_reason']);
            $var->reliever = $this->request->getData(['reliever']);
            $valueSaved = $this->EmpLeaves->save($var);
        }

        if($valueSaved)
        {
            //newcode for sending email
             $applierEmail = $this->Auth->user('office_email');
            $applierName  = $this->Auth->user('first_name') . ' ' . $this->Auth->user('last_name');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Please check the message'));
        }
    }
```